# Ошибка list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x

Задание следующее: скорректировать список `A=(a1, а2, ..., аn)`(в качестве элементов списка случайные числа), переписав в начало списка группу, содержащую наибольшее число подряд идущих положительных элементов.

Идея у меня такая:
создать список, где будут хранится индексы всех положительных элементов, потом сравнивать два соседних числа, если их разница равна 1, то вставлять их индексы в новый список. Но выводит ошибку `while w[k]!=w[-1]:`

> IndexError: list index out of range

```
import random
q = []
w = []
i = []
r = []
k = 0
n = int(input())
for k in range(0,n):
    q.append(random.randint(-100,100))
print(q)
for k in range(0,n):
    if q[k] > 0:
        w.append(k)
print(w)
while w[k]!=w[-1]:  #Вот здесь появляется ошибка
    if w[k]+1==w[k+1]:
        i.append(w[k])
    else:
        if len(i)>len(r):
            r = i
            i.clear()
    k = k+1
print(r)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто поправьте ваш while на:

```
while k<=len(w) and w[k]!=w[-1]:
```

Суть в том, что вы не проверяете индекс на максимальное значение. Максимальный индекс равен len(array)-1